# Conditional relationships? One-to-many relationship using a pivot table for only a type of entity

Tags: database-design, subtypes, condition, relations

I have the following tables:

```
users:
  - id
  - name
  - user_type_id (references id on user_types)

neighborhoods:
  - id
  - name

homes:
  - id
  - house_number
  - neighborhood_id (references id on neighborhoods)

user_types:
  - id
  - label
```

The available user_types are **resident**, **neighborhood_admin**, **super_admin**. Each type of user has access to different parts of the system. Only residents must have a relationship with the `homes` table.

I was thinking adding a pivot table like:

```
residents:
  - user_id (references id on users)
  - home_id (references id on home)
```

but I'm not sure if this approach is correct. I've used pivot tables for many-to-many relationships only. Also, using code I would have to check the user_type before assigning a home, but I could just as easily assign a home to a super_admin if I'm not careful.

How can I make the database enforce this restriction so that it doesn't have to be done through code?

**UPDATE:** I forgot to add, neighborhood_admins must be assigned to a neighborhood. I could add the following table:

```
neighborhood_admins:
   - user_id (references id on users)
   - neighborhood_id (references id on neighborhoods)
```

But this creates a problem. The `users` table now has two different relationships to the `neighborhoods` table; if the user is a neighborhood_admin, then the relationship is obtained from the pivot table `neighborhood_admin` but if the user is a resident, then we must first obtain the `home` relationship and then the home's neighborhood.

I'm thinking I might as well just add a `neighborhood_id` column to the `users` table and be done with it, but I don't like those relationship triangles. Also, that column would be null for super_admins so it couldn't be a foreign key.

Comment: Is the relationship between a "resident" user and a home many-to-many or 1-to-many? (and the same question goes for the relationship between a "neigbourhood" user and a neighbourhood.) Please clarify.

Comment: It would be one-to-many for both cases. Users belong to one home and neighborhood admins manage one neighborhood.

Comment: So a home can have 1 or many users and a neighbourhood is managed by 1 or many neighborhood admins, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't `users` and `neighborhood_admins` be temporal? Thinks tend to change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most RDBMSs you'll have the ability to set-up column conditionals, which are useful for cases like this. Say your user types are 1, 2 and 3 (res, admin, super respectively). You can set `users` this way:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  user_type_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES user_types,
  home_id int NULL REFERENCES homes,
  -- a resident must have a home, a non-resident cannot have a home
  CHECK ((user_type_id = 1 AND home_id IS NOT NULL) OR
         (user_type_id <> 1 AND home_id IS NULL))
);
```